# OnPremise vs. Hosted MS CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Are there any differences between the OnPremise and Hosted versions of MS CRM 2011 besides price/licensing?  Can I deploy solutions or any other custom features to the Hosted version or is that strictly reserved for the default functionality?

We are also considering trying to mold Sharepoint into being our CRM because we are already licensed for it but I'm going to try to reject that.

Comment: Use the right tool for the right job. There is a reason why Dynamics CRM exists in the portfolio. BTW., you also have to have licenses for SharePoint as well (depending on the edition, they are covered by the server CALs)

Comment: You're right, I meant to say that we are already licensed for Sharepoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can deploy plugins that run in the [Sandbox environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334752.aspx) in the CRM Online/Hosted environments.  You can also deploy custom FetchXML-based reports to Hosted.  The main things you can't do in a Hosted environment:

- "Normal" plugins
- SQL-based Reports
- Direct database access (Filtered Views)
- Custom .NET Workflow activities

And yes, SharePoint shouldn't be your CRM - CRM should be your CRM! :)

Comment: If I may add, there's still so much querying you can't do via FetchXML or Linq that having access to the SQL Box for all sorts of queries turns out to be really useful.

Comment: Is direct querying discouraged in the same way that it is for Sharepoint?

Comment: No, as long as you use the Filtered Views. That is what they are there for - direct queries and Reports.

Comment: +1 for the note on the Filtered Views - I'd never used them before!  But I take it the SQL machine has to use Windows Authentication and not SQL Authentication, since MS says so in their comments in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc151204.aspx?

Comment: @jamnap That's right, CRM doesn't support SQL Auth, you must use Windows Auth.

Answer (score 0):

With rollup 12 it is now possible to use custom workflow activities in CRM online

http://mubashersharif.blogspot.be/2013/01/custom-workflowactivity-understanding-development.html